# Material Instance Created in Car Model Prefab

Tags: unity-game-engine

I don't know why my car 3d model's mesh renderer creating own instances of all materials when I spawn it using prefab.
Please check below image for the same:
[image]

My environment models not creating own instances of materials but all cars models doing when I initialize via prefab. 
I hope you are getting my point.

Here I am attaching an image for car model import settings:
[image]

**So I want to stop these new materials instance creation process**

After spawning of car model, it has own material instance created at runtime so I want to solve this problem.

I have created another demo project in that this kind of situation not get created. There is no new instance of material gets created within mesh renderer.

Comment: are you sure the instances are not created *because* you change the colors at runtime?

Comment: If I change color or not - this is not mattered by default new instances get created that is the problem. I want to change color through shared material but the model has created a new one for use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last, I can able to manage the problem myself.

As I understand and learn, if you change the material's any property say as per my case a Color then it will create a new instance of it because you changed something runtime compares to its core version.

In my case, I want to change a car chassis color runtime based on game player selection.
So that new instances of material get created runtime and I lost in access of chassis material to change color.

I require to runtime fetch the material of chassis to change its color.
Here is the code that I used:

```
GetCarChassisMaterial().color = DataCollection.CAR_COLOR_OPTIONS[colorIndex];

Material GetCarChassisMaterial()
{
    Material[] carSharedMats = carChassisMeshRenderers[currentCarIndex].sharedMaterials;
    for (int i = 0; i < carSharedMats.Length; i++)
    {
        if (RemoveInstanceFromName(carSharedMats[i].name).Equals(carsChasisMat[currentCarIndex].name))
            return carSharedMats[i];
    }

    return carsChasisMat[currentCarIndex];
}

// remove "(Instance)" word from runtime created material name
private string RemoveInstanceFromName(string name)
{
    return name.Split(new char[] { ' ' })[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you access renderer's material via code and modify something, Unity duplicate your material (the instance you're seeing) so that it doesn't modify every objects that share this material. If you want to change something globally, either get a reference to the material (not going through the renderer), or create multiple materials and assign the one you want at runtime.

Comment: I have created a chassis material manually and applied to mesh renderer that I hope you can see in the above image. Same material I have assigned to the script. But this material is of no use because the model has created a new one for it.

Comment: If you don't modify the material at runtime, there should not be an instance of your material, I just tested it. So you either are doing something you forgot, or using something from the asset store that doesn't it for you

Comment: And anyway, what is your problem ? Just get a reference to your car, get it's renderer, and modify the color

Comment: Basically, I want to stop the new instance creation process. Color change and all other things I will do myself.

Comment: Why materials new instance get created? this is my question and problem. If I create new project and do the same process then it is not creating new instance for the materials.

Comment: I have updated my question and removed all color changing related discussion so that confusion not get created.